# How to get connection string from appsettings.json without using EF? I want to use in Data Access Layer project separated from my API project

Tags: sql, database-connection, .net-6.0, connection-string

I am developing a Web API using .Net 6 (`Program.cs` only). I am wondering how to get connection string from `appsettings.json` **without using Entity Framework.**

**Note**: I have a Data Access Layer project separated from the rest of my API project - how to get connection string in this separate project?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it.

I created a Class DBConn.cs inside DataAccess Project

Note: Here I have created a static property **Conn** because all my classes and methods inside DataAccess Project as static.

[image]

Controller.cs
[image]

My DataAccess Project
[image]